# How do I vertically align form elements in Bootstrap 3 columns?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

I have the following code, meant to vertically align a button in my Bootstrap form section:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <label for="isbn">ISBN# (10 or 13)</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="isbn" placeholder="0000000000" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <button class="btn btn-default form-isbn" type="button">Check ISBN</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.form-isbn {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    float: none;
}
```

For some reason, it's still not working as it should.  Screenshot attached shows what is happening (seems that vertical alignment is...top by default?  I need the button to sit at the bottom of the row to properly align with the input field that it's next to.

[image: Incorrect alignment!]

Any idea what the issue might be?  I'm sort of dumbfounded, and I have looked at a couple similar questions here on SO, to no avail.  :(

Comment: Use the `form-horizontal` class. Bootstrap doesn't have any special support for aligning forms that aren't either `form-horizontal` or `form-inline`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <label for="isbn">ISBN# (10 or 13)</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="isbn" placeholder="0000000000" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <button class="btn btn-default form-isbn" type="button">Check ISBN</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this help.

*Try to disable the css you made for the .form-isbn

Answer (score 0):

I came across this recently and wanted to achieve the same. One way to achieve with pure bootstrap classes is to push the input and button to a separate row and remove the bottom margin in the first row to bring the label as close to the input as before

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9 mb-0">
            <label for="isbn">ISBN# (10 or 13)</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="isbn" placeholder="0000000000" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Check ISBN</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```